# getArguments() returning null

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I am trying to pass data from an activity to a fragment but wherever I use getArguments it is always null.

Here is my fragment newInstance:

```
companion object {
    private var IS_FROM_SETTINGS : String = "IS_FROM_SETTINGS"
    fun newInstance(isFromSettings : Boolean):OnBoardingLocalitzacioFragment{
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putBoolean(IS_FROM_SETTINGS, isFromSettings)
        val fragment = OnBoardingLocalitzacioFragment()
        fragment.arguments = args
        return fragment
    }
}
```

In the activity I create the fragment doing:

```
 onBoardingFragments = mutableListOf(
            OnBoardingLocalitzacioFragment.newInstance(isFromSettings)::class,
            OnBoardingPresentacioFragment::class,
            OnBoardingNotificacionsFragment::class
    )

    adapter = OnBoardingPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, onBoardingFragments)
```

Then, back in the fragment:

```
arguments?.getBoolean(IS_FROM_SETTINGS)!!
```

I've tried using the get arguments in different methods but still no luck.

Thanks :)

Comment: provide fragment class code

Comment: `back in the fragment:` where exactly?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko anywhere in the fragment. Aaraon and savepopulation are right. But still couldn't find a workarround.

Answer (score 1):

You're just passing classes into your list, my guess is that `newInstance` is never called, and all of your fragments are instantiated differently in `OnBoardingPagerAdapter` without taking any arguments.

Answer (score 1):

In your method below:

```
onBoardingFragments = mutableListOf(
            OnBoardingLocalitzacioFragment.newInstance(isFromSettings)::class,
            OnBoardingPresentacioFragment::class,
            OnBoardingNotificacionsFragment::class
    )
```

You're passing your fragment's `class` not `instance` which you're trying to create with `newInstance` fun. I think you're creating a new instance of your fragments in your adapter from it's class. So your arguments is null.

Here's an example code:

```
 onBoardingFragments = mutableListOf(
            OnBoardingLocalitzacioFragment.newInstance(isFromSettings),
            OnBoardingPresentacioFragment(),
            OnBoardingNotificacionsFragment()
    )
```